# Efficiently extracting webpage data into a data structure with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, stackexchange

I am new to JS and I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to perform this task.

Stack Exchange keeps a list of its member-sites at  https://stackexchange.com/sites

What is the most efficient way to extract this data into a data-structure, like an array or dictionary in JavaScript?

Comment: You mean like `http://stackexchange.com/sites`?

Comment: Where do you want to implement it? In a chrome extension? In a web app? Where?

Comment: Check for `window.StackExchange` maybe?

Comment: @MehulMohan chrome extension

Comment: For a chrome extension, you can get current site by using the background.js file defined in manifest and then matching it against array or whatever you want.

Comment: See my updated question. I tried to make it a useful one, since apparently the old question was terrible.

Comment: Why not to use their API? https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like all the stackexchange sites are built with the same framework. If you check in your console, you can see that a javascript object `StackExchange` is defined on any stackexchange site.

If you just want to scrape that link in your question, you can go there in your browser, and type this in your console: `$('.gv-item-collapsed-wrapper h2').text()`

That page already has jQuery loaded, which you can use to search through elements on the page. That code snippet will show you all the site titles in a string.

Better yet (but a little more complex)

```
var arr = [];
$('.gv-item-collapsed-wrapper h2').each(function(){arr.push($(this).text())});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested a small portion of the sites, and this seems to work:

```
window["StackExchange"] !== undefined
```

If you look at the source of any page, there is always something like this:

```
StackExchange.ready(function () {
```

So basically you're checking to see if that class, `StackExchange` exists, and if it does, most likely (I'm sure in the masses of the internet, somebody is borrowing/stealing the code or using the same name) a StackExchange site.